# How to append an item to an array in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Hi im trying to append an item to a dynamoDB array.

```
exports.handler = (event,context,callback)=>{
let params = {
    Key:{
        "userName":event.userName,
    },
    UpdateExpression:"set #FutureTrips = list_append(if_not_exists(#FutureTrips,empty_list),country)",
    ExpressionAttributeNames:{
        "#FutureTrips" : "FutureTrips"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':country':["Japan"],
        ":empty_list":[]
    },
    TableName:"Users"
    };


dynamoDB.updateItem(params,function(err,data){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        callback(null,err);
    }
    else{
        callback(null,data);
    }
});
```

};

it returns me   "message": "Unexpected key '0' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':country']",

im trying to append an item to an array called FutureTrips
thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you share, currently the **UpdateExpression** is not referring to the specified **ExpressionAttributeValues**.

```
UpdateExpression:"set #FutureTrips = list_append(if_not_exists(#FutureTrips,empty_list),country)"
```

Correct UpdateExpression should be;

```
UpdateExpression: "set #FutureTrips = list_append(if_not_exists(#FutureTrips, :empty_list), :country)"
```